# c# : Window goes to second monitor then jump back to main monitor

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, multiple-monitors

Hi below are the simplified code, it's strange that the window stay at the second monitor in a split of second then come back to the first main monitor. There must be a window setting or external program cause it so. Because the same code works in ANOTHER computer with dual screen. And I am sure and double checked that the second monitor is in index 1 : showOnMonitor(1, Q);

```
 Q = new queue(); 
 showOnMonitor(1, Q);
 Q.Show();

public static void showOnMonitor(int monitor, Window w2)
        {
            Screen[] sc;
            sc = Screen.AllScreens;

            if ( monitor >= sc.Length )
            {
                monitor = 0;
            }


            w2.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;

            var workingArea = sc[monitor].WorkingArea;
            w2.Left = workingArea.Left;
            w2.Top = workingArea.Top;
            w2.Width = workingArea.Width;
            w2.Height = workingArea.Height;

        }
```

Comment: Breaking the showOnMonitor in debug can tell you why.. Did you try breaking on it?

Comment: Good idea, I will try that.

Comment: @tagaPdyk It's strange, using the debug mode step by step, the window goes to the second monitor without jumping back to the first even until the end of execution.

Comment: @tagaPdyk Okay, now I found out that the window actually follow my cursor, if my cursor is placed on the second monitor then only it will show there. Why ?

Comment: I don't know if this can be related, but seeing that in your code you receive the window as a parameter, i tell it. I've noticed that the default setting for WindowStartupLocation has to be made in the constructor to work properly so maybe the WindowStartupLocation.Manual should be set by the code creating the window (or set inside the window class code if you have it).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I don't know why this works. But it's the solution.

```
Q = new queue();
Q.Show();
Thread.Sleep( 100 ); //need to delay first before moving the position
showOnMonitor(1, Q);

public static void showOnMonitor(int monitor, Window w2)
        {
            Screen[] sc;
            sc = Screen.AllScreens;

            if ( monitor >= sc.Length )
            {
                monitor = 0;
            }


            w2.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;

            var workingArea = sc[monitor].WorkingArea;
            w2.Left = workingArea.Left;
            w2.Top = workingArea.Top;
            w2.Width = workingArea.Width;
            w2.Height = workingArea.Height;

        }
```